# How to filter an array by properties inside an array of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm trying to filter every establishment in the `establishments` array by whether `specialCategories` is found in the array `establishmentSpecials` of the `establishments` array itself.

I'm able to filter for the `establishmentSpecials` array for every establishment but I want to keep the establishment portion, as evident by the image.

```
            //masterEstablishments array is from the db

            //The categories array, to filter out all but the following
            specialCategories = ["Breakfast Special"];

            //The array to hold the filtered establishments
            var establishments;

            //For all Establishments
            for(var i=0;i<masterEstablishments.length;i++){
                //Filter out Catorgory from establishmentSpecials where Category is not found in specialCategories
                establishments = masterEstablishments[i].establishmentSpecials.filter(x => specialCategories.includes(x.Category));
            }

            console.log("Filtered establishments");
            console.log(establishments);
```

In summary, for example

```
        var establishments = [ {address: "55 Garden rd"},
            [{Category: "Breakfast Special"}, {Category: "Dinner Special"}]
          ];
```

Should become

```
        establishments = [ {address: "55 Garden rd"},
            [{Category: "Breakfast Special"}]
          ];
```

since "Dinner Special" is not in specialCategories

```
specialCategory = [{Category: "Breakfast Special"}]
```

Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: [Images of text are difficult to read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve (i.e. show expected output given an input and explain the logic)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be filtering the main array, not the `establishmentSpecials` property. Use `array.some()` to check whether any of the specials is in the special categories array.

```
establishments = masterEstablishments.filter(e => e.establishmentSpecials.some(x => specialCategories.includes(x.Category)))
```

Comment: This keeps the establishment portion/the establishment is filtered, but now the establishmentSpecials array isn't filtered.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you just wanted to remove {Category: "Dinner Special"} on the Establishments?

```
        specialCategories = ["Breakfast Special"];

        const establishments = establishments.map((element) => {
          return {
            Cuisine_Type: element.Cuisine_type,
            Address: element.Address, // add the other properties so on and so forth
            establishmentSpecials : element.establishmentSpecials.map((ES_element) =>{
              if (ES_element.Category === specialCategories[0]) {
                return ES_element;
              }                  
            })});
```